# find the mean of an array of 1000 random integers javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble with calculating the mean value of an array of 1000 random numbers. The array holds 1000 random number between 1 and 30.

I also want to be able to count how many of each number occurred in the array and print the amount of each number in a frequency distribution table.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">


var arr = [];

    function getRandom( num ){
         return Math.round(Math.random() * num)+1;
    }

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     arr.push(getRandom( 30 ));
  }
  document.write(arr);
  document.write("<br/>");

  for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){

     sum += parseInt(arr[i]);

   }

   var mean = sum/arr.length;

    document.write("The sum of all the elements is: " + sum + " The mean is: " + mean);

     </script>
```

Comment: What is the problem which you are getting???

Comment: why are you calling `parseInt` on a value that's already an integer number?

Comment: do not use `document.write`. `console.log` is the best for debug output, and most other output is done after the initial load (in which case `document.write` _cannot_ be used)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to run the cycle twice. Do everything on the fly:

```
var distrTable = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   var rnd = getRandom(30);
   sum += rnd;
   arr.push(rnd);
   if (!distrTable[rnd]) {
       distrTable[rnd] = 0;
   }
   distrTable[rnd]++;
}
```

Now the variables contain the following information:

`arr` - all random numbers.

`distrTable` - each random number with frequency.

`sum` - the sum of all random numbers.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKRZb/)

Comment: Iterating twice doesn't cause the original problem, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak, didn't notice the mistake in the second loop condition, but _it_ caused a problem )

Comment: notwithstanding this is (fractionally) more efficient, it's good to be able to separate the logical actions of _creating a random array_ from subsequently _taking the average of that array_.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, if you're wondering why your code is not working... Here are the reasons:

1. First of define the variable sum. Before the loop just put `sum = 0;`
2. Second of all, while the array is long 1000 items, in the second for you loop for 1001 times. The declaration should be as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) // not i <= 1000;
```

Then the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial error in your code is that in your second loop you are running up to element 1001 instead of element 1000.

Since that element is `undefined`, it causes a sum of `NaN` and the mean, likewise.

To fix, change the `<= 1000` to just `< 1000`

You should also remove the `parseInt` call - that's only necessary if your input values are *strings*, but your array already contains numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Beware when you generate random numbers like this:

```
function getRandom( num ){
     return Math.round(Math.random() * num)+1;
}
```

... this code can generate numbers from 1 to 31! It's because of the `Math.round` -- if `Math.random()` generates `0.99`, `0.99 * 30` will equal `29.7`, that will be rounded to `30`, and then `1` will be added!

The solution is to replace `Math.round` with `Math.floor`.

Comment: This doesn't cause the original problem, however.

Comment: But it fixed another problem, and I hope that counts.